# How can I update the usernames/emails in Git commits?

Tags: git

I wish to update the usernames for a user in the Git history, is this possible?

It was a blunder of mine, I migrated from CVS a while ago and didn't realise until everyone started using the Git repo that I missed a few usernames.

Comment: It looks like this [can only be done destructively](http://help.github.com/changing-author-info/), however I was looking for something that wouldn't update the SHA1 ID's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want git-filter-branch.  As an example, to change the email address of every commit in the entire history, you can do:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=new_address
```

You can set up the filter to only modify commits based on whatever criteria you need.  For example, if you want to set the email address for all the commits authored by "Barry", do

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = Barry; then
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=barrys-correct-address
fi'
```

This will modify the SHA1s of every commit.

Answer (score 3):

What about these commands ?

```
$ git config --global user.name "name"
$ git config --global user.email "name@gmail.com"
```

or maybe you want that :

https://serverfault.com/questions/12373/how-do-i-edit-gits-history-to-correct-an-incorrect-email-address-name

Answer (score 2):

Since the author and committer name and emails are part of what is hashed to produce the commit ID, it is not possible to do this to an existing repository without changing the commit IDs.